# Moved Column with imported data and also moved formulas... How do I move just values (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On my spreadsheet:

1. Row 1 is a typed in header
2. Column I row 2 downward is imported numbers using this formula

```
=INDEX(FILTER('IV Flipped'!2:2,'IV Flipped'!2:2<>""),COUNTA(FILTER('IV Flipped'!2:2,'IV Flipped'!2:2<>"")))
```

1. I drag the formula down to populate the rest of column I
2. I have a button that I assign script to that will move column I to column C from row 2 down.

```js
function MakeEndingStarting() {

  // get sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // get range of column I (9) starting with row 2
  var columnsToMove = sheet.getRange(2,9,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1);

  // move range to column C (3) starting at row 2
  columnsToMove.moveTo(sheet.getRange(2,3));

}
```

How do I modify this code so that it only moves the values to Row C and not the underlying formulas?

Thanks so much for the consideration

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to get only the values instead of "moving"the columns. You could try with:

```
    function MakeEndingStarting() {
    
    // get sheet var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
    // get range of column I (9) starting with row 2 
var columnsToMove = sheet.getRange(2,9,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    
    // move range to column C (3) starting at row 2
    sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(columnsToMove);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about using `copyTo` instead of `moveTo`? In the case of `moveTo`, the cell values are moved by including the formulas and the text styles. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. When this is reflected in your showing script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function MakeEndingStarting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var columnsToMove = sheet.getRange(2, 9, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);
  columnsToMove.copyTo(sheet.getRange(2, 3), { contentsOnly: true });
  columnsToMove.clearContent(); // If you want to move, please use this line. By this line, "I2:I" is cleared after the cell values were copied.
}
```

- When this script is run, the cell values of "I2:I" are copied from "C2" without the formulas.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: @Tillthen BigHeart About `Perfect! Thanks so much!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer